# Include external common files in terraform

Tags: terraform, provider

I have this provider.tf file where I am calling provider.tf file from common directory
`../../common/provider.tf`

../../common/provider.tf

```
provider "vault" {
  address = "https://localhost"
  auth_login {
    path = "auth/approle/login"

    parameters = {
      role_id   = "var.VAULT_ROLE_ID"
      secret_id = var.VAULT_SECRET_ID
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this error when trying at terraform plan

Error: Argument or block definition required

on provider.tf line 1:
1: ../../common/provider.tf

An argument or block definition is required here.

Comment: That's not how this works. You have to have the provider defined wherever you intend to use it.